# Collection view height incorrect when used with UIPageControl

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

## Overview

There is a `UICollectionViewCell` that contains an imageView.

Above the collection view there is a `UIPageControl`

The image is got from the photo library and displayed.

## Problem

- The first time alone the image in collection view exceeds the top boundary.
- `UIPageControl` height is not determined while the collection view loads.
- I get the following error:

### Error:

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
```

## Points to note:

- This `UICollectionViewController` is added as a child controller to `UIStackView`.
- The above problem only occurs for the first time, when I remove from child view controller and add again, the issue is resolved.

## Question:

- Why is the image overflowing it's boundaries in spite of setting constraints and using aspect fit ?
- How to fix this issue ?

## Collection View Cell:

```
class PhotoBrowserCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    let imageView = UIImageView()


    //MARK: Initializers

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }


    //MARK: Setup

    private func setup() {

        setupBaseView()
        setupImageView()
    }

    private func setupBaseView() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }

    private func setupImageView() {

        imageView.image         = UIImage(named: "PlaceHolder")
        imageView.contentMode   = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        imageView.setContentHuggingPriority(1000, forAxis: .Vertical)

        contentView.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 30, right: 20)

        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: insets.left).active = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -insets.right).active = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.topAnchor, constant: insets.top).active = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -insets.bottom).active = true
    }
}
```

## Request Asset from photo library:

```
private func requestAssetSelected() {

    let size = imageViewSize

    if let assetSelected = assetSelected {

        cachingManager.requestImageForAsset(assetSelected,
                                            targetSize: size,
                                            contentMode: .AspectFit,
                                            options: nil) { [weak self] image, info in

            //This completion handler might be called multiple times
            //First time it provides a temporary image and then shows a full size image
            //So ensure it is not a temporary (degraded) image
            if let image = image,
                    isDegraded = info?[PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] as? Int where isDegraded == 0 {
                self?.imagesToUpload.append(image)
                self?.photoBrowser.reload()
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        photoBrowser.reload()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Root Cause:

- The collection view cell height calculation was wrong
- Cell height was wrong because the collection view height was wrong
- Collection view height was wrong because the `UIPageControl` was zero while collection view was populated. And much later the `UIPageControl` height was computed.
- `UIPageControl` was using it's intrinsic size.

This is the reason why it only happened the first time.

## Solution:

Add a height constraint, so that it doesn't have to depend on it's intrinsic height calculation:

```
pageControl.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(38).active = true
```

Answer (score 0):

==> Height is wrong so set constrain....

==> This link will help you to solve all your problems related to heights and Constrains

```
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KImie4ZMwk
```

### Thank you for sharing your problems

.

Comment: In my case collection view height is not fixed. The collection view height = screen height - page control height. So depending on the screen size the collection view will grow / shrink

Comment: So you don't want to set constraints ?? Right!!

Comment: I am using constraints and UIStackView. It is just that collection view height is not hard coded.

Comment: https://github.com/mgcm/FlexibleLayoutStackView/blob/master/Flexible%20Layouts%20with%20Swift%20and%20UIStackView.md

Comment: for flexiable layout for stackview

Comment: no proble will you send me code if possiable i want to check that code i have hungery to know more will you pls

Comment: Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/